# extracting and parsing wikipedia articles

Tags: html, xml-parsing

I have wikipedia articles in xml format and I need to extract just the words in the articles for a project. I've no experience in XML parsing. Are there tools or libraries out there that extracts all the words?

Comment: The best way to start would be Googling `extracting and parsing wikipedia article` and adding the name of the programming language of your choice.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Here's quick and dirty: http://bit.ly/16WJEPo

Answer (score 1):

If you like Python, [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is a great option.

If you don't like Python, get to know Python.

Answer (score 1):

[Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) is a powerful Ruby library that would do what you need.

It allows you to to traverse XML and HTML documents and use xpath or CSS3 selectors to select certain elements, like the article text.

Comment: Also a fine choice. I happen to think Python has a lower barrier to entry than Ruby if you are starting from scratch with both, but if you like Ruby (as I do too), this is a great option.